# How to show items from only two libraries with Content Query Webpart

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, content-query-web-part

Salvete!  I have two document libraries, and want to display the contents of both libraries in one view.

Can I do this with the Content Query Webpart?
Is there a way to make it display in the same list format like the originals?

What I want to accomplish is the equivalent of having a document library that loads from two sources.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by using ListsOverride property and specifying the GUIDs of the two document libraries from which you want to query the data. Something like this:

```
    <property name="ListsOverride" type="string">
    <![CDATA[<Lists><List Id="{5a2f79bb-cc82-4171-88ac-65f20e7b5fa8}" /></Lists><List ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}"/>]]>
```

Comment: Never thought of that.  After I try it, I'll give my comments...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no out of the box method in the CQWP where you can specify to fetch the items from only 2 lists.

However, you can specify a particular Content Type from which to fetch the items. So if you can specify a special Content Type for your 2 libraries, then it can be specified in the CQWP and only the items from these 2 libraries will be fetched.

Edit: As mentioned by @Nadeem,  Another option would be to use the ListsOverride property of the CQWP in which you can specify the Guid of the lists to fetch the items from. Only caveat with this approach would be that you will not able to make any customizations from the UI after that. Have a look here:
http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/06/querying-specific-lists-with-the-content-query-web-part.html

Comment: That is a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I dont know if this will be any help to you but i would expect it to be just what you need :)

http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/displaying-results-in-multiple-columns-using-the-content-query-web-part/

hope this helps :)